# Failed to create artifact while running batchlet

Tags: java, jax-rs, batch-processing

I get this error while trying to run a batchlet:

> 16:05:35,807 WARN  [org.jberet] (Batch Thread - 1) JBERET000001: Failed to run batchlet org.jberet.job.model.RefArtifact@2dea3d8a: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBERET000600: Failed to create artifact with ref name MyBatchlet.  Ensure CDI beans.xml is present and batch.xml, if any, is configured properly.
>       at org.jberet.runtime.context.JobContextImpl.createArtifact(JobContextImpl.java:185)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.AbstractRunner.createArtifact(AbstractRunner.java:156)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.BatchletRunner.run(BatchletRunner.java:66)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.runBatchletOrChunk(StepExecutionRunner.java:229)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.StepExecutionRunner.run(StepExecutionRunner.java:147)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runStep(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:164)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.CompositeExecutionRunner.runFromHeadOrRestartPoint(CompositeExecutionRunner.java:88)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.runner.JobExecutionRunner.run(JobExecutionRunner.java:60)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.batch.jberet.impl.BatchEnvironmentService$WildFlyBatchEnvironment$1.run(BatchEnvironmentService.java:243)
>       at org.wildfly.extension.requestcontroller.RequestController$QueuedTask$1.run(RequestController.java:497)
>       at org.jberet.spi.JobExecutor$3.run(JobExecutor.java:161)
>       at org.jberet.spi.JobExecutor$1.run(JobExecutor.java:99)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>       at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: JBERET000600: Failed to create artifact with ref name MyBatchlet.  Ensure CDI beans.xml is present and batch.xml, if any, is configured properly.
>       at org.jberet.creation.ArtifactFactoryWrapper.getClassFromBatchXmlOrClassLoader(ArtifactFactoryWrapper.java:65)
>       at org.jberet.creation.ArtifactFactoryWrapper.create(ArtifactFactoryWrapper.java:41)
>       at org.jberet.runtime.context.JobContextImpl.createArtifact(JobContextImpl.java:183)
>       ... 15 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyBatchlet from [Module "deployment.idkwebapp.war:main" from Service Module Loader]
>       at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:363)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:351)
>       at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:93)
>       at org.jberet.creation.ArtifactFactoryWrapper.getClassFromBatchXmlOrClassLoader(ArtifactFactoryWrapper.java:63)
>       ... 17 more

I've created a beans.xml but I still couldn't get it to work...

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>
```

Here's the batchlet:

```js
package br.com.idk;

import javax.batch.runtime.context.JobContext;
import javax.batch.runtime.context.StepContext;
import javax.inject.Inject;

public class MyBatchlet {

  @Inject JobContext jobContext;
  @Inject StepContext stepContext;

 public String process() throws Exception {
  
     long executionId = jobContext.getExecutionId();
  
     System.out.println("I'm a cool batchlet!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
     
  return null;
 }

 public void stop() throws Exception {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 } 
 
 
}
```

Here's where I call it:

```js
package br.com.idk;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.batch.operations.JobOperator;
import javax.batch.runtime.BatchRuntime;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/hello")
public class Resource {
 
 @GET
 @Path("testBatch")
 public Long testBatch() {
  JobOperator jobOperator = BatchRuntime.getJobOperator();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("name", "Dude");
        
        return jobOperator.start("simple-batchlet-job", props);
 }
}
```

Here's the XML for the job:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job id="simple-batchlet-job" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee">
    <step id="myBatchlet">
        <batchlet ref="MyBatchlet"/>
    </step>
</job>
```

Answer (score 1):

alter your beans.xml with  bean-discovery-mode="all" like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans
        xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
        bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```